# pop function in Python

Tags: python

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
a.pop(a[0])
print(a)
output:
[1,3,4]
```

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
a.pop(0)
print(a)
output:[2,3,4]
```

What is the difference between these two( a.pop(a[0]) and a.pop(0) )?

Thank you!

(This is the first time that I'm asking a question on this platform, sorry if it is inappropriate)

Comment: The signature is `pop(index)` meaning you remove the element at index

Comment: This boils down to the difference between `0` and `a[0]`.

Comment: Did you try reading the documentation?

Answer (score 3):

When you're doing `a[0]` you're returning the first item in the list, which is `1`. When you do `pop(a[0])`, you're essentially doing `pop(1)`. So the difference is `pop(0) != pop(1)`.

Comment: Thank you! Really appreciate it! But shouldn't a[0] mean 1 from the list a = [1,2,3,4] So, shouldn't it pop 1?

Comment: @Ramnishanth no, it will pop the element at *index 1*.

Comment: `a[0]` evaluates to `1`, and then `pop` removes the element at index 1, which is the `2`.

Answer (score 3):

whatever you pass in a.pop("here") is the index of the List
so

```
a.pop(a[0]) # pops a[0] which is 1 therefore it becomes
a.pop(1)  # this will pop the first index of the list
```

similarly in your second part

```
a.pop(0)  # will remove the 0th index of the list.
```

Answer (score 1):

a.pop(0) pops the item with index 0.
a.pop(a[0]) pops the item with index 1 as a[0] = 1.

Comment: Thank you! Really appreciate it! But shouldn't a[0] mean 1 from the list a = [1,2,3,4] So, shouldn't it pop 1?

Comment: The argument passed to pop function works as an index. So instead of popping the element with the value of 1, it pops the element at the index 1 which is the second element of the list.

Answer (score 0):

The code implementation is done from the inner bracket to the outer one
• NB:  a[0] ==1, a[1] ==2, a[2] == 3 and a[3] ==4
• In the case of a.pop(a[0]), a[0] returns the element at the first index which in this case is 1. Then a.pop(a[0]) evaluates to a.pop(1). So the value of a at index 1 gets popped. Hence the list becomes [1,3,4] with the item formerly at index 1 has been popped.
• In the case of a.pop(0), the item at index zero on the list, which is 1, gets popped off.